# Book where people in a town commit suicide after a vision of the Virgin Mary

Tags: identification-request

I'm looking for a book I read years ago but can't remember the title.

It takes place in a town that is maybe French, Italian or Mediterranean.

The town's people regularly commit suicide after a vision of the Virgin Mary, who calls out to them. She says a word that's like "adjao".

It had an orange cover.

Comment: Was it a novel, a factual book, or a story in a longer book? What genre was it, it a ghost story, a thriller, literary fiction, comedy? When did you read it? How old was the book? When was it set? Was the book from the US, UK, some other country? Can you remember any characters or events? Was it for adults or children? Did it have any pictures? Was it thick or thin?

Comment: Hi Sarah, identification requests are on topic on this site, but they usually require a bit more information than you have provided. Could you please check the [tips for identification requests](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and edit your question improve it?